# citus rebalance_table_shards() -> fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: citus

Version: postgresql 14 and citus 10.2

When I execute

`select rebalance_table_shards('tbl_name');`

in the CN node, postgresql gives an error message: ERROR:  connection to the remote node localhost:5432 failed with the following error: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

what's configurations needed to be added?

1. Firewall of all nodes are disabled.
2. local and ipv4 lines in the pg_hba.conf of all nodes have been set to trust.

Thanks!

Comment: I fixed it by modified pg_hba.conf, configuring local, ipv4, ipv6 to be trust.

Comment: Hello I have the same problem. I set pg_hba.conf as stated here: https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v10.2/installation/multi_node_debian.html#steps-to-be-executed-on-all-nodes
But problem persist. Do you have a sample pg_hba.conf file?

Answer (score 4):

The rebalancer connects to localhost and it seems you don't allow that in pg_hba.conf without a password. There's a few ways you could solve this:

1. add an entry for localhost to your .pgpass file, with the password for the localhost IP, both for ipv4 and ipv6 (127.0.0.1 and ::1)
2. add an entry `pg_dist_authinfo` with the `-1` nodeid and `password=....`
3. add an entry to pg_hba.conf to allow passwordless logins from localhost, by using trust authentication
4. If you are on Citus 10.1 or higher, you can set citus.local_hostname to something that currently is in your pg_hba.conf file (like the node its public IP). It will then connect to the hostname/IP that you specify there instead of to localhost: https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v10.2/develop/api_guc.html#citus-local-hostname-text

Comment: Thx for your solution, it's work for me now.

Comment: @jeltef I am having same issue, Trying to run this on co-ordinator node.  sudo -i -u postgres psql -c  "SELECT * from citus_add_node('20.40.43.246', 5432);"
what configuration do i need to add in worker that is 20.40.43.246?